# How to zip multiple folders separately in linux

Tags: linux, shell, zip, gzip, redhat

Below mentioned folders contain some data. I need to zip all the folders separately.

```
ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-1       
ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-4  
ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-7
ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-3      
ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-5  
ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-8
ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-2      
ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-6
```

With this Command, I can zip only one folder

```
zip -r ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-3.zip ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-3
```

How can I zip all the folders separately at once?

Comment: "How can I zip all the folders separately at once?" is not clear. Do you want to end up with eight zip files, each with one folder? Or do you want one zip file with eight folders?

Comment: I want eight zip files, each with one folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that you are in the directory where the above mentioned folders are. Then run:

`find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -execdir zip '{}.zip' '{}' \;`

This will find all the directories and zip them with the names:

```
ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-1.zip
ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-4.zip
ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-7.zip
ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-3.zip
ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-5.zip
ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-8.zip
ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-2.zip
ItembankUpdate-20210602-NGSS-6.zip
```

Comment: `maxdepth 0` will not pack anything inside folders. `*` will exclude current directory. So I made this: `find * -type d -maxdepth 0 -execdir zip -r -0 '{}.zip' '{}' \;`